# Download large csv file using json2csv in node js

Tags: node.js, express, json2csv

i am using json2csv package for downloading my data it is working fine for small data. but if the records are more then 300 values it gets crashed. here is my code

```
const csvString = json2csv.parse(responseData);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=shifts-report.csv');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.status(200).send(csvString);
```

this code is working perfectly fine on small data how can i stream data when there is large amount of data using the same approach that i followed.

---

i am trying something like this but it gives me an error that cannot set the headers.

```
const headers = {
      'Content-type': 'text/csv',
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="file.csv"'
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.flushHeaders();
    const stream = new Writable({
      write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        res.write(chunk);
        callback();
      }
    });
try {
        stream.write(file, 'utf-8');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      }
    }
    res.end();
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and its intended output. There may be optimisations that are possible based on the data being parsed.

Comment: here is the dummy data formate that i am passing to download. the data is downloading perfectly i am trying to download this using chunk by chunk i posted below the approach.
responseData = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": 40000,
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": 35000,
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": 60000,
    "color": "green"
  }
];

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Json2CSV stream` instead.

```
npm install json2csv-stream
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
const MyStream = require('json2csv-stream');


// create the one-time-use transform stream
const parser = new MyStream();

// create the read and write streams
const reader = fs.createReadStream('data.json');
const writer = fs.createWriteStream('out.csv');

//You can use writer to write it to the FS
// or can stream the content to the response object
// however, you need to write this code in any route handler
// which is sending the CSV data back to the user
reader.pipe(parser).pipe(res);

//reader.pipe(parser).pipe(writer);
```

For more details check [here](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv-stream).

Comment: FYI: You have initialised `writer`, but you don't use it.

Comment: Also this package is deprecated, because OP's package has a streaming interface.

Comment: okay i'll check using json2csv-stream package

Comment: @samthecodingman Yes, I just kept it for ref if the he wanted to store it on the FS, updated the answer with info.